# How to get better smooth subdivision corners

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to round off the corner section on the mesh, but the outer line is more sharper than
the inside one. I tried moving the outer vertices to get better result. but its pinching the mesh and looks incorrect.

[image]

Comment: https://cgcookie.com/articles/guide-to-clean-topology
you can also try moving your pole (5-edge) to the flatter top surface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use this kind of topology? You'll be able to precisely control the corner roundness:

[image]